# ViewModel modify data, layout doesnt recognize

Tags: java, android, mvvm

I have a EpisodeViewModel with a propertie called `seen`

If the user click on the item, I want to change the Bool var `seen` to true.

In episode_item.xml I defined a `ImageView` with this src

`src='@{viewModel.seen ? @drawable/ic_check : @drawable/ic_check_false}'`

But If I change the `seen` value at the parent SeasonArrayAdapter, nothing happened.

I thought, if I change the variable, the UI recognize this new value.

Here are some code snippets:
The episode_item.xml snippet:

```
<CardView...>
    <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="34dp"
                    android:layout_height="34dp"
                    android:id="@+id/episode_seen"
                    android:src='@{viewModel.seen ? @drawable/ic_check : @drawable/ic_check_false}'/>
</CardView>
```

The EpisodeViewModel:

```
public class EpisodeViewModel extends BaseObservable {
    private TvEpisode episode;
    private Context context;
    private Boolean seen;

    public EpisodeViewModel(Context context, TvEpisode episode) {
        this.episode = episode;
        this.context = context;

        this.seen = false;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.episode.getName();
    }

    public void setSeen(Boolean seen) {
        this.seen = seen;
    }

    public Boolean getSeen() {
        return this.seen;
    }
}
```

And the parent SeasonArrayAdapter function:

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(this.context.getApplicationContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View v, int pos) {
                    final TvEpisode episode = adapter.getItemAt(pos);

                    EpisodeItemBinding binding = (EpisodeItemBinding)DataBindingUtil.getBinding(v);

                    EpisodeViewModel viewModel = binding.getViewModel();
                    viewModel.setSeen(true);
                    ....
```

At least the RecyclerView Helper:

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
    }
}
```

Does I need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface? Or is it already included by the BaseObservable class?

Comment: you need to call `notifyChange` or even better `notifyPropertyChanged` inside `setSeen`

Comment: Hello @pskink Thanks for the fast and working answer :-)

Comment: did you use `notifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: only `notifyChanged`
I have some trouble with the `BR` object

Comment: see @Bindable annotation then

Comment: now it works. Thanks a lot